# dataframe - extracting URL in pandas and creating new columns out of it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parsing, url

“I have a dataframe called products and one columns has the url that I'm 
     trying to splits.

```
  ID         URL
  101015    https://defrost/kskswn_sourcefsr_3rt=forst23=rt5s_campaign10=new_york65007
  "
```

I'm trying to see if it is possible to split the url in multiple part in order to understand where people click on the link and which campaign they click

```
The goal is to have anything between the equal sign '=' in its own columns

I try this code and a bunch of others 

 def parse_url(files_1):
   for index, row in files_1.iterrows():
     parsed = urlparse(str(row)).query
     parsed = parse_qs(parsed)
     for k, v in parsed.items():

        df.loc[index, k.strip()] = v[0].strip().lower()
  return files_1

 parse_url(files_2['CLICK_URL'])

The goal is to have something like this:
ID       COL1                                            COL2              COL3

101015   https://defrost/kskswn_sourcefsr_campaign_3rt  rt5s_campaign10  new_york65007
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% what your code is doing but IIUC, you can pass your `URL` column into a list of lists and iterate over it to assign to columns :

```
data = df['URL'].str.split('=').tolist() # pass urls to list with split method.
```

### Iterate over our list with enumerate,

```
for list_ in data: # access indvidual list (rows) 
    for number,item in enumerate(list_,start=1): 
        df[f'COL {number}'] = item # assign to columns
```

## Result.

```
print(df)
    ID  URL COL 1   COL 2   COL 3   COL 4
0   101015  https://defrost/kskswn_sourcefsr_3rt=forst23=r...   https://defrost/kskswn_sourcefsr_3rt    forst23 rt5s_campaign10 new_york65007
```

Comment: @cesco no problemo my man, if this answered your question please green tick so this can be closed